# Custom User meta field display

Tags: plugins, custom-field, users, pods-framework

I'm using PODS plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/) to extend main types in wp and WP Tiles for tiles rendering (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-tiles/). I'v already added field position to user type (it's meta). And i try to call it so (in Text-Only Byline Template):

```
<span class="author-name">%author%</span>
<span class="author-position">%meta:position</span>
```

but it render's me:

```
admin %meta:position
```

what i do wrong, and how to display this custom User meta fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second line you forgot the closing `%` after `meta:position`